# DMARC without rua... proper format?

Tags: dmarc

Yahoo and Google are now requiring DMARC according to Shopify. I have been setting them up for my clients, but I don't need the aggregate reporting. I only need it so that these companies can verify the legitimate sender if needed.   I read that you can remove the rua  but want to make sure that the client emails are still accepted.  Currently, i have it written as :
v=DMARC1; p=none; rua=mailto:dmarc-reports@mydomain, mailto:artist@mydomain
Would I instead use
v=DMARC1; p=none;   mailto:artist@mydomain  ??
I am not sure how the verification works with the dmarc. My host adds the _dmarc.mydomain  so I don't have to add that.

Comment: So,  the mailto:email addresses are NOT needed to validate emails coming from the domain URL?   That is the real reason for my question. I don't think my non tech clients want to receive reports and won't know what they are or mean.  I just want to make sure that their domain name emails are validated

Answer (score 0):

You will only receive DMARC reports if you set the rua tag, a minimal DMARC record to comply looks like this:

```
v=DMARC1; p=none;
```

The [tags](https://easydmarc.com/tools/dmarc-record-generator#dmarc-explanation-tags) that can be used for the record are:

> - v (required) - The version tag. The only allowed value is "DMARC1". If it's incorrect or the tag is missing, the DMARC record will be
>   ignored.List item
> - p (required)   - The DMARC policy. Allowed values are "none", "quarantine", or "reject". The default is "none," which takes no
>   action against non-authenticated emails. It only helps collect DMARC
>   reports and gain insight into your current email flows and their
>   authentication status. "quarantine" marks the failed emails as
>   suspicious, while "reject" blocks them.
> - rua - Aggregate report sending destination. It's the "mailto:" URI that ESPs use to send failure reports. The tag is optional, but you
>   won’t receive reports if you skip it.
> - ruf - Forensic (Failure) report sending destination. It's the "mailto:" URI that ESPs use to send failure reports. The tag is
>   optional, but you won’t receive reports if you skip it.
> - sp - The subdomain policy. The subdomain inherits the domain policy tag (p=) explained above unless specifically defined here. Like the
>   domain policy, the allowed values are "none," "quarantine," or
>   "reject." This option isn't widely used nowadays.
> - adkim - The DKIM signature alignment. This tag follows the alignment between the DKIM domain and the parent Header From domain.
>   Allowed values are "r" (relaxed) or "s" (strict). "r" is the default
>   and allows a partial match, while the "s" tag requires the domains to
>   be the same.
> - aspf - The SPF alignment. This tag follows the alignment between the SPF domain (the sender) and the Header From domain. Allowed values
>   are "r" (relaxed) or "s" (strict). "r" is the default, and allows a
>   partial match, while the "s" tag requires the domains to be exactly
>   the same.
> - fo - Forensic reporting options. Allowed values are "0," "1," "d," and "s." "0" is the default value, which generates a forensic report
>   when both SPF and DKIM fail to produce an aligned pass. If either of
>   the protocol outcome is something other than pass, use "1." "d"
>   generates a report when DKIM is invalid, while "s" does the same for
>   SPF. Define the ruf tag to receive forensic reports.
> - rf - The reporting format for failure reports. Allowed values are "afrf" and "iodef". pct  The percentage tag. This tag works on domains
>   with "quarantine" or "reject" policy only. It marks the percentage of
>   failed emails a given policy should be applied to. The rest falls
>   under a lower policy. For example, if "pct=70," on a domain with
>   "quarantine" policy, it applies only 70% of the time. The remaining
>   30% goes under "p=none". Similarly, if "p=reject" and "pct=70,"
>   "reject" applies to the 70% of failed emails, and the 30% go into
>   "quarantine."
> - ri - Reporting interval. Marks the frequency of received XML reports in seconds. The default is 86400 (once a day). Regardless of
>   the set interval, in most cases, ISPs send the reports at different
>   intervals (usually once a day). v The version tag. The only allowed
>   value is "DMARC1". If it's incorrect or the tag is missing, the DMARC
>   record will be ignored.

Don't forget to use SPF and DKIM otherwise, DMARC will not work.

You should consider using a DMARC processing service to detect any unauthorized usage of your domain and guarantee deliverability in the future.

Please take some time to read a little more about DMARC at https://dmarc.org/

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR: `v=DMARC1; p=none;` is syntactically valid but doesn't make any sense in practice.**

You are taking the easy way out and it will backfire. It is true that the [Google's Feb 1, 2024 requirements](https://support.google.com/a/answer/81126#zippy=%2Crequirements-for-sending-or-more-messages-per-day) regarding DMARC are loose. On the other hand, the next requirement looks like Google would be requiring *alignment*  even with the `p=none` policy.

> - Set up DMARC email authentication for your sending domain. Your DMARC [enforcement policy](https://support.google.com/a/answer/10032169#policy-options) can be set to `none`. [Learn more](https://support.google.com/a/answer/81126#dmarc)
> - For direct mail, the domain in the sender's From: header must be aligned with either the SPF domain or the DKIM domain. This is required to pass [DMARC alignment](https://support.google.com/a/answer/10032169#alignment).

But that's just the very beginning of using DMARC policies. The `p=none` is for transition phase where you don't yet know whether the delivery of legitimate would pass an actual DMARC enforcement. You are stating that you don't need  the aggregate reporting, but I disagree. Getting and reading the aggregate reports is the only way to gain the knowledge required for smooth email delivery in the next phase. Furthermore, Google & Yahoo might start to enforce that next, too.

You also say that the companies should be able "to verify the legitimate sender if needed". The `p=none` does not provide that; it says that we are taking a step forward DMARC enforcement, but at this point we don't care how the receiver treats email spoofed from our domain.

Later, when you have at least `p=quarantine` and your email infrastructure is static and stable you *might* remove the `rua=` with the consequence that you wouldn't know if legitimate mail starts to get quarantined. With `p=reject` you would know that from the rejected messages. However, e.g., [Microsoft treats](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/226270/enforcing-dmarc-policy-reject-on-an-office-365-tenant) `p=reject` just like it was `p=quarantine`.